# Get Value from range from another sheet to list

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to get values from the `column A` of the sheet "Listing", to use it in a combo box in the "Menu" sheet.

Here the code of the menu sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect([4:7], Target) Is Nothing  And Target.Count = 1 Then
     ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Delete
        Set CB = Me.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Target.Left, 
        Top:=Target.Top, Width:=60, Height:=15)
        With CB
            .name = "CB"
            .OnAction = "CB_Change"
            .List = Worksheets("Listing").Range("A1").Value
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

The `Worksheets("Listing").Range("A1").Value fails` and I get an

> error 438: object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lst

    If Not Intersect([4:7], Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        With Worksheets("Listing")
            lst = "'" & .Name & "'!" & _
               .Range(.Range("a1"), _
                      .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address()
        End With

        Me.DropDowns.Delete
        With Me.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Target.Left, _
                                      top:=Target.top, Width:=60, Height:=15)
             .Name = "CB"
            .OnAction = "CB_Change"
            .ControlFormat.ListFillRange = lst
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't write in those combo box, only select a choice. Any ways to write things ?